# JSON.parse: Invalid character when returned from ASP.NET WebMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

In an ASP.NET web application, I have a `WebMethod`. I am calling this web method from a jQuery AJAX post request. And I want to return the result as a json object.

My web method:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string OnSubmit(string Email, string Message)
    {
        EmailHelper.sendSupportEmail(Email, Message);
        string message = "Thank you for your submission, we will be looking into it as soon as possible.";
        int status = 200;

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ReturnResult result = new ReturnResult() { Status = status, Message = message };

        return serializer.Serialize(result);
    }

    public class ReturnResult
    {
        public int Status {get;set;}
        public string Message{get;set;}
    }
```

Basically I'm just calling the `sendSupportEmail` function and then I serialize it to Json using the JavascriptSerializer and return it.

Client side I have

```
    $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Contact.aspx/OnSubmit",
                data: data,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert("Oops, we are unable to process your request at this time. Please try again later.");
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                    var status = obj.Status;
                    var message = obj.Message;

                }
            });
```

The request is success however I get an error on the `jQuery.parseJSON(result);`

> JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

I tried to write the json string myself but still didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Open your browser's development console, put a breakpoint at line `Query.parseJSON` and see the content of `result`.

Comment: @L.B I get the following: "{\"Status\":200,\"Message\":\"Thank you for your submission, we will be looking into it as soon as possible.\"}"

Comment: The `result` you provided works fine with `JSON.parse()`, I don't see the problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I had to use `result.d`

So the code would be

`var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result.d);`